# Уровень вложенности ссылки на PHP

Tags: php, url

На данный момент, что требуется и в чем возникает сложность.

1. Требуется результат, когда например прописываю в одном месте что-то такое:

```html
<li><a href="/'.$lang.'/page/">'.$trans['link-text'][$lang].'</a></li>
```

2. Чтобы получить в независимости от вложенности папки результат (но находясь в главной папке), реальные примеры:

```html
<li><a href="/kz/ru/page/">Подробней</a></li>
<li><a href="/kz/kz/page/">Көбірек</a></li>
<li><a href="/kz/en/page/">More</a></li>

<li><a href="/kz/page/">Көбірек</a></li>
<li><a href="/ru/page/">Подробней</a></li>
<li><a href="/en/page/">More</a></li>
```

- Чтобы можно было получить результат вот такой "**/kz/ru/page/**" находясь по URL: https://www.site.com/kz/ru/  ;  соответственно, чтобы получить такой уже результат "**/kz/page/**" когда как посетитель нахожусь по URL: https://www.site.com/kz/

Текущий код, но он не решает в нужном ключе (кроме подстановки текста в зависимости от языка), возможно сможете подсказать решение для URL.

```html
$lang = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1]  ?? 'en'; 
$trans['more'] = ['kz' => 'Көбірек', 'en' => 'More']; 
echo '<a class="btn" href="/kz/'.$lang.'/page/" data-class="block">'.$trans['more'][$lang].'</a>';
```

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, вы пытаетесь реализовать мультиязычность (наверное)... `/kz/ru/` - это как? вывод должен быть одновременно на двух языках?) Подозреваю, вы сами не совсем понимаете что хотите сделать) предоставьте, будьте так любезны, больше информации и конкретизируйте проблему...

Comment: @Jour
 Спасибо, что обратили. Логика в следующем как написал в вопросе: <Чтобы можно было получить результат вот такой "/kz/ru/page/" находясь по URL: https://www.site.com/kz/ru/ ; > - иными словами, главная папка в данном примере, это "../ru/".

Comment: В самом деле, сейчас больше сложности в формировании вложенности папки, чем в постановке текста. Ведь есть и другой пример: <li><a href="/kz/astana/page/">Көбірек</a></li> - как видно, даже находясь на стр. /kz/astana/ - подстановка текста происходит на казахском языке и это правильно. Но, с URL сложней, приходится что-то такое писать: href="/'.$lang.'/astana/page/"

Comment: @Nicolo *"главная папка в данном примере, это "../ru/""* --- а зачем там тогда kz? Сделайте как чаще всего делают.  Делаете функцию, например `t()`, и везде в шаблонах её используете. например `t('more')` или `t{'next'}` ...... Далее в проекте заводите папку `translations` и там распологаете переводы на разные языке в формате ключ-значение..... ... функция `t` должна считать язык из URL (и он должен быть там только один. и как правило он указывается через GET параметр, т.е. `?lang=ru`.... либо вы должны знать, что язык всегда идёт первым параметром)

Comment: и дальше из нужного файла на основе языка из URL взять перевод по указанному ключу в папке `translations/ЯЗЫК/язык.php`  например `translations/ru/ru.php` или `translations/kz/kz.php` .... в принципе можно и без доп папки.

Comment: В ссылках писать `/kz/LANG` не имеет смысла с логической точки зрения...проще гет параметр накинуть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы как всегда на высоте))) там где я негодую и желаю послать на ВЦ автора, вы все красиво расписываете)) как обычно, лайк от меня)) будь я геем, я бы на вас запал)))))) ... но на самом деле я просто ору с таких вопросов, пропуская следующие 50 гр)

Comment: В текущем коде в принципе у вас тоже плюс минус.  С этим жить можно... Только надо бы писать не `$trans['more'][$lang]`, а `$trans[$lang]['more']` ..... А по URL уже описал: просто для перевода должен быть только **один** язык. Потому что запись в виде `/kz/ru/en/gb` будет просто некорреткна с любой точки зрения.... И тогда,  вы точно знаете, что на `[0]` в url у вас всегда язык  и просто на него ориентируетесь...... если без ЧПУ - то на GET параметр (например `lang`).... Сразу становится легче жить

Comment: Ну а массив должен быть таков: `$trans = ['kz' => ['more' => бла бла бла, 'next' => блаблабла2, 'hello' => блаблабла3], 'ru' => ['more' => ещё, 'next' => сдежующий, 'hello' => здрастье]]`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский

<"главная папка в данном примере, это "../ru/"" --- а зачем там тогда kz?> - Огромное Вам спасибо, попробую, но вначале отвечу с другим примером, который увы не соотносится с этим примером (видимо нужно было в вопрос включить более объемный вариант применения). Итак.

- Имеется один язык (китайский) для нескольких стран, соответственно об этом сообщается в HEAD и в Sitemap.xml, пример, первого:

Comment: <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.site.com/zh/" hreflang="zh-cn">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.site.com/zh/hk/" hreflang="zh-hk">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.site.com/zh/sg/" hreflang="zh-sg">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.site.com/zh/tw/" hreflang="zh-tw">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.site.com/zh/th/" hreflang="zh-th">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.site.com/zh/vn/" hreflang="zh-vn">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.site.com/zh/id/" hreflang="zh-id">

Comment: Соответственно, если мы открываем здесь: https://www.site.com/zh/sg/page/  -  то язык остается основной "zh" (упрощенный кит.). Но, с тем кодом который я Вам привел, мне нужно все время дописывать: href="/zh/'.$lang.'/page/" (для получения: href="/zh/sg/page/") - что не удобно, более того, иногда (это видимо я сам накосячил), получается и вовсе вот так: href="/zh/'.$lang.'/page/" - результат: href="/zh/zh/page/".

Код на перевод работает, а вот с URL нет.

Comment: Просто сделайте проще. Как я писал - сделайте это через GET параметры. Как это сделано в google translate . Например `?sl=en&tl=ru` и просто считывайте этот параметр или добавляйтев URL с помощью PHP, если его нет. Тогда в ссылках ничего не придётся писать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский

Еще раз спасибо. Я, попробовал вот так:

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path= parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$result = array_pop(explode("?", trim($path, "/")));
//print_r($result);

И я приблизился к цели, вот что получается:

<li><a href="/'.$lang.''.$result.'/page/">TXT</a></li>

Результат, для меня удивительный: <li><a href="/zhzh/sg/page/">TXT</a></li>

В коде вначале вместо "?" вписал "/", а потом понял, что теряю слэш, но зато нет дублирования "zh".

Как можно сохранив слэш, не дублировать папку выше?

Comment: Попробовал используя простой способ: echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  -  и здесь проблема в дублировании вместе с текущим кодом на уровне: "ZH" = /zhzh/, а если открывать на странице: /zh/sg/ = /zh/sgsg/.

<li><a href="/'.$lang.''.$result.'/page/">TXT</a></li>
<li><a href="/'.$lang.''.basename($item->url).'/page/">TXT</a></li>